# How to hide the default browser scrollbar in an Angular component?

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, firefox, scrollbar

I figured out how to hide the scrollbar globally in an Angular app, but I ran into a scenario in my actual project where I need to hide the default scrollbar in a singular Angular component but have the default scrollbar visible in other components. ::host seems to not solve this problem. If anyone knows how to solve this problem, I would greatly appreciate the feedback! Also, if possible, I would love a CSS solution as I feel there shouldn't be any crazy solutions & or hacks to solve this. I made a quick stackblitz below...

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-syr7do?file=src/styles.css

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0px !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  width: 0px !important;
  background-color: whitesmoke !important;
  border-radius: 0px !important;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
  width: 0px !important;
  background-color: white !important;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal {
  width: 0px !important;
  background-color: whitesmoke !important;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

Replace `*` with a specific class/id if you want.

Dont forgot to add `overflow:auto`

Comment: I want to hide the scrollbar from the angular component and not from the global styles.css. As this explanation you have works in the styles.css file but not in the test components css file.

Comment: I have mentioned like replacing the class / id with global selector

Comment: Check stackblitz please. I implemented that code in the test component that you gave me and the default scrollbar still appears

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5ucaua check out this now. i have done small changes

Comment: I am tryin to hide the default scrollbar in the component itself, not in the content class in your forked stackblitz or the paragraph tag in my stackblitz, and not in the global styles. Hope that helps. For some reason ::webkit-scrollbar doesn't work in the test component css itself

Comment: For entire page try to replace `*` with `body` - Hope it will help bro @JustinNobles

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for Internet explorer and Edge */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to hide the default scrollbar for the entire test component in the component itself and not globally, not just for a single class/id

Answer (score 0):

For hiding scrollbar in body globally put

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

in your CSS file.

And using custom scrollbar in the other component, you just need to wrap in a container your content and set your custom scrollbar.

Here is the a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nztuts?).